# Unable to run hive queries using spark engine

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have set the below properties in my hive shell

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
set spark.home=/home/kiran/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6;
set spark.master = spark://ACD-KIRAN:7077;
set spark.eventLog.enabled = true;
set spark.eventLog.dir=/home/kiran/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-events;
set spark.executor.memory=512m;
set spark.serialzer = org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer;
```

When i am trying to execute any query that includes a map reduce job, i am getting this error

```
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException(RPC channel is closed.)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you check if there is something running on ACD-KIRAN port 7077 ?
eg. what's the output of `nmap -p 7077 ACD-KIRAN` ?

Comment: I have checked it using the web UI localhost:8080 it says Spark Master at spark://ACD-KIRAN:7077 and when i run this nmap command it says port is open and service is unknown.

Comment: port is open => that's good.

Comment: Now is there any solution for this?